# Is it possible to not reload a particular section of the page without the usage of iframe in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Eg. I have a `div` that is there inside all my views but still I have to reload it everytime thereby slowing down the page loading rate. So is there a way to not reload the part of the page?

Answer (score 2):

you should consider using Ajax...
AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

check this page, it's an easy step by step to learn the very basics : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can go with Ajax and only reload those parts of the page you need.

Comment: Ajax would not be that helpful because I just want to keep 1 div intact and the rest page to be changed. So to change it everytime it wouldn't be a good option

Comment: You can do that with Ajax very easily.